# super() call in sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence, diagram

How do you represent a super() call in a sequence diagram? I create a class "Bar", which is a subclass of "Foo". While creating this class Bar, the default constructor of Foo gets called to. How do you draw that in a sequence diagram?

Answer (score 0):

A super call represents a call to some method of the superclass, so if class A extends from class B then:

```
class A extends B{
    public A (){
        super();
    }
}
```

And

```
class B {
    public B (){
        ...
    }
}
```

You have to think of this classes in runtime, so for example you have an object a from class A called a, this object is represented by both classes since class A extends class B.

In this case I would do a diagram with the constructor of the super class B, so I can link this diagram to the diagram in which I represent the constructor of the class A.

Since the call to the super class constructor refers to the same object a not another object the message arrow should be a self message in which it calls to the constructor of the super class B.

Additionally to make things more clear I would add the code of the super call.

Something more graphical should be this.

[image: Sequence Diagram for class A]

And for class B

[image: Sequence Diagram for class B]

PD. I Use Enterprise Architect software to do the diagrams.